# show that $\sum_{l=1}^{d}\sin^2(\frac{\pi j l}{d+1})=(1/2)(d+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I show that the following is true

$$\sum_{l=1}^{d}\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi j l}{d+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(d+1\right)$$

$j=1,2,3,..,d$

I am not sure how what strategy to use to prove this $J

Comment: What is $j$? (2 more characters to go... xD)

Comment: What is the parameter j.

Comment: oh yeah $j=1,2,..d$

Comment: Is this double summation?

Comment: it is one summation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Euler fomula:

$$
\sum_{l=1}^{d}\sin^2(\frac{\pi j l}{d+1})=\\
-\frac14\sum_{l=1}^{d}( \exp{(i \frac{\pi j l}{d+1}}) - \exp{(-i \frac{\pi j l}{d+1}}))^2 = \\
-\frac14\sum_{l=1}^{d} \exp{(2i \frac{\pi j l}{d+1}}) -\frac14\sum_{l=1}^{d} \exp{(-2i \frac{\pi j l}{d+1}}) -\frac14\sum_{l=1}^{d}(-2) \\
-\frac14(-1)-\frac14 (-1) -\frac14\sum_{l=1}^{d}(-2) \\
= (1/2)(d+1)
$$

where you have used that, if $j$ is not an integer multiple of $d+1$,

$$
\sum_{l=1}^{d}\exp{(-2i \frac{\pi j l}{d+1}}) =\sum_{l=0}^{d}\exp{(-2i \frac{\pi j l}{d+1}})  -1 = -1
$$

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

For $\theta \in \Bbb R$ and $\beta\in\Bbb R $,

$$\sin^2 (\theta)=\frac {1-\cos (2\theta)}{2} $$

and

$$\cos (\beta)=\frac {e^{i\beta}+e^{-i\beta}}{2} $$

then use geometric sums.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative **hints**:

1. Is there [some particular polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html) having its roots at $\sin\left(\frac{\pi j l}{d+1}\right)$ for $l=1,2,\ldots,d$?
2. How can we use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) to compute the sum of the squares of the roots of a polynomial, given its coefficients?

Comment: @stressed-out: this is a pretty well-known trick, indeed. Euler (and later Cauchy, too) used it to prove that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6},$$ which is Basel problem.

Comment: The brilliant part was that you fast realized that there were roots of a polynomial. I could look at them for months and do not see it. The rest was ordinary. This shows once more that the curriculum of math students should cover more about special functions, generating functions and combinatorial relations and I'm completely clueless in those departments, unfortunately.